# py2exe error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe

I'm trying to turn a python project into a .exe file using py2exe, but I'm getting the error error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect. It still creates the .exe file, but it crashes as soon as launched. I'm running Python 3.9.6 and Windows 10.

Here is my setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup 
import py2exe
setup(console=['GUI.py'])
```

And here is the full error message:

```
running py2exe
selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.pyc:208: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?

  12 missing Modules
  ------------------
? PIL                                 imported from openpyxl.drawing.image
? Queue                               imported from urllib3.util.queue
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? backports                           imported from urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
? brotli                              imported from urllib3.response, urllib3.util.request
? collections.Mapping                 imported from urllib3._collections
? collections.MutableMapping          imported from urllib3._collections
? defusedxml                          imported from openpyxl.xml, openpyxl.xml.functions
? numpy                               imported from openpyxl.compat.numbers
? openpyxl.tests                      imported from openpyxl.reader.excel
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? test                                imported from multiprocessing.util
Building 'dist\GUI.exe'.
error: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect.
```